# Parse the JSON response

Tags: java, json, restful-url, phrase

i am trying to phrase the below json response and the get the "`message`" and "`WORKORDERID`" data in java

```
{
    "operation": {
        "result": {
            "message": " successfully.",
            "status": "Success"
        },
        "Details": {
            "SUBJECT": "qqq",
            "WORKORDERID": "800841"
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my code

```
JSONObject inputs = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
JSONObject jsonobject = (JSONObject) inputs.get("operation");
String s = jsonobject.getString("message");
system.out.println("s");
```

Comment: you print the String `"s"` instead of variable `s`

Answer (score 3):

Your objects are nested 2 times, therefore you should do:

```
JSONObject inputs = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

JSONObject operation= (JSONObject) inputs.get("operation");
JSONObject result= (JSONObject) operation.get("result");
JSONObject details= (JSONObject) operation.get("Details");
String message = result.getString("message");
String workerId = details.getString("WORKORDERID");
```

Comment: It the answer solved your problem, it's nice if you accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject is somethink like Map-Wrapper, so you can think, that your JSON data-structure is `Map<Map<Map<String, Object>, Object>, Object>`. So, firstly you need to access to datas by first key (operation), secondly (result) and after that, you can access to desired field (message).

*Note, that value of Map is Object, so you will need to cast your type to JSONObject.*

Answer (score 0):

sometimes JSONObject class is not found in java. so you will need to add [jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonlib24jdk15jar.htm)

```
try{
   // build the json object as follows
   JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonString);
   // get operation as json object
   JSONObject operation= (JSONObject) jo.get("operation");
   // get result as json object
   JSONObject result= (JSONObject) jo.get("result");
   JSONObject details= (JSONObject) jo.get("Details");
   // get string from the json object
   String message = jo.getString("message");
   String workerId = jo.getString("WORKORDERID");
}catch(JSONException e){
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```